# Netsuite - Saved search: Show kits available

Tags: formula, netsuite, saved-searches

For a netsuite saved search I and trying to find a formula that does the following.

- Have a saved item search display Kits only if all members of the kits have...
- (Quantity available / member quantity) >3
  I've been netsuite with support and they have no clue what to do about this.

Any suggestions or examples are appreciated.
-Brandon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a summary search criteria

[image: saved search summary criteria]

You will need to group by the kit id or description field

[image: saved search results grouping]